# Integral in regularization involving exp of a parameter in the denominator

Tags: integration, regularization

Can someone please point me a way to compute
$$\int_0^\infty\frac1{s+t}\exp\left(-\alpha t+\frac{t^2\beta}{s+t}\right)dt$$
? How about the following one?

$$\int_0^\infty ds\int_0^\infty dt\,\frac1{s+t}e^{-(s+t)}e^{-\frac{st}{s+t}}$$

Comment: Sorry. I'm trying to use the Schwinger parameters to compute an integral. Please move it if necessary.

Comment: No, no, I was just asking for more information. I assumed it was physics-related, but I didn't know just what the connection was. Thanks.

Comment: You can either use an old style integral table to find the solution, or you can use a symbolic math tool like Mathematica (there is also freeware that does the same). If neither offers a solution, there is, in all likelihood, no closed form for this integral. FYI, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%28s%2Bt%29*exp%28-a*t+%2B+b*t*t%2F%28s%2Bt%29%29 returns that there is no solution in terms of standard functions. That's a bad sign.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help, if you define$$
I(\alpha,\beta) =\int_0^\infty\frac1{s+t}\exp\left(-\alpha t+\frac{\beta}{s+t}\right)dt
$$
You could show that the function $I$ satisfy the PDE
$$
\alpha \partial_\alpha I - \beta \partial_\beta I = \alpha\,s\,I-\exp(\beta s)
$$
Maybe studying this PDE you could solve the integral.